# JavaScript - Test if page was searched by user on browser

Tags: javascript, html, search, browser, onload

I want to make it so my webgame cannot be searched using javascript. Example:

- Enter url in browser search box
- If so, redirect to page
- Without doing it on `onload`.

**HTML** -  **JavaScript**

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this?

Comment: so you can't just seacrh the url and go to a certain level. Forget about the question, I'm learing PHP soon, can you do this in PHP?

Comment: I'm not that good, but you can look at the referrer to see if the user was coming from a search engine site, and then print out '<!--' to make the page disappear if the user was searching for it. *But, again, there are lots of search engines!*

Comment: You don't need to craft individual URLs for it. Just put it on one page and use POST.